# Can ${}_2F_1\left(1,b;1+b;z\right)$ be simplified?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I would like to ask a question about hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1$. Specifically, I hope to solve the equation
$$
\frac{\delta x}{1-\delta}{}_2F_1\left(1,1-\delta;2-\delta;x\right)=a,
$$
where $\delta\in\left(0,1\right)$ and $a\geq 1$. Is the $x$ has the closed-form solution? If not, for the special case when $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$, can we get $x$?

I think the above hypergeometric function has the special structure, but I checked the literatures and cannot find useful results. I appreciate if you can help to solve it, or give some suggestions.

Thanks.

Comment: You can solve numerically and in this case you need to give specific values for $a$.

Comment: $${}_2F_1(1,\frac12;\frac32;x) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}\log\left(\frac{1+\sqrt{x}}{1-\sqrt{x}}\right)$$

Comment: Hi @MhenniBenghorbal, Thank you for your comments. For numerical results, I can get it for given value of $a$. Thanks~

Comment: Hi @achillehui, Thank you. It's helpful. I also found that when $\delta=\frac{1}{2}$, the above hypergeometric function can be expressed by arctanh() function. But I still cannot obtain the closed-form solution of the equation, right? -_-||